DataTable is not initialized when returned data is empty
We have a dynamic set up of DataTable v1.10.20 to initialize a datatable event if data is empty as it will be filled up with specific data when the select option is selected.
Now we updated jQuery version to 3.7 and DataTable v2.0.6 and somehow the table is stuck on displaying process/loading with length menu and search option on top displays fine.
DataTables 2.0.6, Buttons 3.0.2, Responsive 3.0.2, RowReorder 1.5.0, Select 2.0.1
response:
{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":0,"recordsFiltered":0,"data":[]}
window.tableInit = function()
  {
  var $table = $('#tableId')
    .DataTable(
      { paging     : true
      , serverSide : true
      , searching  : true
      , pageLength : 10
      , responsive : true
      , processing : true
      , pagingType : 'simple_numbers'
      , lengthMenu : [[5, 10, 25, 50],[5, 10, 25, 50]]
      , ajax       : { url: 'url here', type: 'POST' }
      , columns: 
        [ { data: 'id'    }
        , { data: 'image' }
        , { data: 'name'  }
        , { data: null    } ]
      , sDom       : 'dom structure'
      , bSort      : true
      , columnDefs: 
        [ { width:  '5%', targets: 0 } 
        , { width: '20%', targets: 1 } 
        , { width: '50%', targets: 2 } 
        , { targets: [ 1, 2] , bSortable: false } 
        , { responsivePriority: 1, targets:  0 } 
        , { responsivePriority: 2, targets: -1 } 
        , { targets : -1
          , data    : null
          , mRender : function( data, type, full )
            { 
          return `<div>
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-order" title="Select">
                      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>`;
          }
        , bSortable : false
        , sClass    : 'dtActionCls'
        }
      ]
    }
  ).columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();
    
  return $table;
  }

var $listTable = tableInit();

$("#tableId").on("init.dt", function()
  {

  // this part doesn't get appended on top of the table
    
  $("#tableId_wrapper .filter .selection")
  .html('<div class="selection"><select><option value="" selected>Select</option><option value="option1"></option<option value="option2"></option></select></div>');
  });


Check for breaking changes in the major release version (v1->v2): https://datatables.net/upgrade/2

you have typo errors on your last line: bad double quotes. next time please respect some code indentation, this will even yourself help to see this kind of error.

What happens if you change "draw":0 to "draw":1 in the JSON response?

Just to elaborate... Look at the initial Ajax request sent by your DataTable. I suspect it will have "draw": 1 in there - and therefore your response should match that value. The response should cast the request value to integer and then return it in the response, to ensure correct sequencing of potentially multiple async responses. See here. Don't just keep sending the same hard-coded value in the response (and don't send a draw response value which is less than the draw request value).

@andrewJames, If I change "draw":1 in the JSON response the table continues to initialized therefore, added the selection html in the filter.

Sorry, I did not understand your comment. Also, did you look at the initial Ajax request sent by your DataTable? What was the request value for draw?

@andrewJames my previous comment is for your question last 12 hours ago. The initial ajax request of the DataTable is {"draw":0,"recordsTotal":0,"recordsFiltered":0,"data":[]}

The request value for draw is 1

@andrewJames on the php side the value for draw is hard coded to 0

That is a problem. Don't hard code the value to 0. Use the request value. If that does not help, then there is some other problem you are facing which I think is missing from the question. I cannot help you with that, obviously.

The issue is on the php code back end as the 'draw' value is hard coded equal to 0. My co-developer on the back end change it to be dynamic, getting the request value for 'draw'
